# QGIS cannot read local Google Drive data on OSX Ventura?

Tags: qgis, google, osx

I'm running OSX Ventura and store my GIS data on Google Drive so that my whole team can share. Problem is, Ventura just apparently implemented a change to move the location of the local storage for Google Drive to /users/library/cloudcontent/..., and users/library/, as you may already know, is a hidden system folder that Apple does not allow the user to un-hide. Because QGIS does not use Apple's file browser, but instead rolls its own file browser, it is unable to see /users/library/, and thus completely unable to access any data stored on Google Drive.

I'm now dead in the water until I figure out how to allow QGIS to see Google Drive folders again.

Any advice? Currently upgrading QGIS from LTR to the latest release to see if maybe the file browser has been upgraded...

Comment: [Mirror instead of stream](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124#zippy=%2Cswitch-from-streaming-to-mirroring)?

Comment: No, I don't see how that has any relevance. Files still go to the same hidden folder, which QGIS cannot see.

Comment: According to the docs "When you switch from streaming to mirroring, My Drive will no longer appear in your Google Drive streaming location... Your My Drive files will be downloaded to the folder *you choose* when configuring this option."